# BiodiversityR installation - Non-Zero Exit Status

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm attempting to install the R package BiodiversityR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiodiversityR/index.html). However, I run into a non-zero exit status during installation. From what I can tell it is due to other uninstalled dependent packages (see code below); however, none of the packages in the error code are listed as needed on the CRAN package description.

Additionally, I have installed Rtools (RTools43 Bash), which is noted to be required. But not sure if there is more that I need to do besides install the application (I assume there is, but I cannot find instruction on how to use it to successfully install BiodiversityR). At a loss of what to do here. I tried to include the code in this post, but it was flagged as spam. Happy to provide to anyone who could help.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge.

Comment: There are quite a few packages required (https://github.com/cran/BiodiversityR#packages-needed); which one/s are causing you trouble?

Comment: Than you for your reply! It starts with 'htmltable'. When I attempt to install 'htmltable' I get an error that requires 'htmlwidgets'. When I attempt to install 'htmlwidgets' I get an error that 'htmltools' is needed. I have 'htmltools' installed, but not the latest version. When I attempt to update 'htmltools' I get the following message: " There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
            binary source needs_compilation
htmltools    0.5.5  0.5.7              TRUE
htmlwidgets  1.6.2  1.6.4             FALSE
htmlTable    2.4.1  2.4.2             FALSE"

Comment: Additionally, the install starts with a warning message that Rtools is not installed. I do have the Rtools application installed on my computer, but as noted in my previous message, the Rtools package within Rstudio will not update to the latest version.

Comment: When you say "the Rtools package within Rstudio will not update to the latest version", the rtools version should match your version of R (so if you're using R 4.2, install rtools42; R 4.3 use rtools43). If Rtools isn't installed correctly it could very well be the root of your problem. Did you follow the install instructions from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/?

Comment: Sorry, I conflated 'Rtools' with 'htmltools'. 'htmltools' is the package within RStudio that I cannot seem to update to the most recent version. I have the 'RTools43 Bash' application installed on my computer. Reading the instructions online it would seem that I wouldn't need to do anything else for "RTool43 Bash' to work with RStudio to build the BiodiversityR package, but perhaps it is installed in the incorrect location. This could be my own ignorance and perhaps I am out of my depth in my ability to use R. Thank you again for your time, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If rtools is installed it should 'just work' - if it's not installed correctly perhaps try installing it again. Also, please confirm you've tried `install.packages("htmltools")` and selecting 'no' when asked if you want to compile from source? Then retry installing biodiversityR. I'd also recommend emailing the biodiversityR package author (RoelandCEKindt@gmail.com) and let him know you're having trouble installing the package - it's very likely he'll help you solve the problem

Comment: Thank you again for your help and time! I just re-ran through everything in my code and I think that I found the issue - which was admittedly very simple and I'm embarrassed as to why I didn't see it before. RStudio was running an older version of R that didn't match the version of Rtools installed. However, the next hurdle I am facing is the following:  
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
    binary source needs_compilation
DBI  1.2.0  1.2.1             FALSE
ps   1.7.5  1.7.6              TRUE

Is there a correct response to have the install proceed?

Comment: Success! My computer was not allowing the pop-up window to appear. The package was successfully installed. Thank you, again, so much. I appreciate your time and wish there was a way to pay you back!

Comment: Happy to help; glad you solved your problem :)